# Navigation in web application with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, navigation

Now I've come to a situation when I need to make navigation in my web application with AJAX async requests. Before navigation was done just with simple hyperlinks <a>

My application is a **ASP.NET** web forms application, consists of master page and a set of pages. Master page and every "child" page has their own CSS and JS files. JS files are named like `page_name1.js`, `page_name2.js`, etc and have some functions with the same name like `ClientPageLoaded()`, `UpdateClientData()`, etc

So now I try to use jQuery `$.ajax` to load html content of the page that user wants to navigate to. For example the user wants to navigate from `page_name1.aspx` to `page_name2.aspx`. Html content loads great to desired html container. Then I also need to change CSS and JS files in <head> for the new content.  So when I change "href" parameter in <link rel="stylesheet" href=...> browser takes new styles and apply them. But when I change "src" parameter in <script type="text/javascript" src=... > and try to call some function like ClientPageLoaded() so the browser uses the old one from page_name1.js instead of page_name2.js

Are there any thoughts how I can solve this problem or maybe solve this "navigation with AJAX" task the other way?